# Jenkins declarative pipeline expression with boolean environment variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm using Jenkins declarative pipeline and I want to make a conditional step depending on an environment variable, which is set according the existence of a file.

So I just want to make something like that : if Dockerfile exist, perform next stage, else don't.

To perform this I tried  :

```
pipeline {
    // ...
    stage {
        stage('Docker') {
            environment {
                IS_DOCKERFILE = fileExists 'Dockerfile'
            }
            when {
                environment name: 'IS_DOCKERFILE', value: true
            }
            stage('Build') {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or :

```
pipeline {
    // ...
    stage {
        stage('Docker') {
            environment {
                IS_DOCKERFILE = fileExists 'Dockerfile'
            }
            when {
                expression {
                    env.IS_DOCKERFILE == true
                }
            }
            stage('Build') {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In both cases, the Dockerfile exist and it is in the workspace. I also tried with strings (`"true"`) but everytime, the pipeline continue without executing the stage 'Build'.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Most pipelines reside in Jenkinsfile which is kept together with the other code in a repository. Assuming this is your case too, the repository either has Dockerfile or it doesn't. I can't see the point of discovering this at runtime.

Comment: This is because I'm trying to use the same pipeline for two application types : web services (which have a Dockerfile) and libraries (which doesn't have a Dockerfile). The only difference is that the library don't need to be built as docker image, so I tried to perform the last step only if the is a Dockerfile. I use a jenkins shared library so the pipeline is common (maybe bad practice)

Comment: You should use a different pipeline for each project. Having said that, you can have a stage which looks if there is a dockerfile using `fileExists`, and sets a global variable. Another stage may then look at the global variable using e.g. `when { expression { IS_DOCKERFILE == true }}` or `script { if (IS_DOCKERFILE) { ... } }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because the exprsssion:

```
IS_DOCKERFILE = fileExists 'Dockerfile'
```

Creates the environment variable with boolean value as string:

```
$ set
IS_DOCKERFILE='false'
```

So the solution would be to use `.toBoolean()` like this:

```
environment {
    IS_DOCKERFILE = fileExists 'Dockerfile'
}
stages {
    stage("build docker image") {
        when {
            expression {
                env.IS_DOCKERFILE.toBoolean()
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'fileExists'
        }
    }
    stage("build libraries") {
        when {
            expression {
                !env.IS_DOCKERFILE.toBoolean()
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'fileNotExists'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

As @Sergey already posted, the problem is that you're comparing a string to a boolean. See [fileExists: Verify if file exists in workspace](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#fileexists-verify-if-file-exists-in-workspace).

Besides his answer, you can compare directly to a string:

```
environment {
    IS_DOCKERFILE = fileExists 'Dockerfile'
}
stages {
    stage("build docker image") {
        when {
            expression {IS_DOCKERFILE == 'true'}
        }
        steps {
            echo 'fileExists'
        }
    }
    stage("build libraries") {
        when {
            expression {IS_DOCKERFILE == 'false'}
        }
        steps {
            echo 'fileNotExists'
        }
    }
}
```